# Extract name from raw text using Python

Tags: python-3.x

"Name of the informant  :   N. K. Sangle, PC B.No. 1775 Traffic Control Branch, Ahmednagar"I have this raw text how can I extract the name of the person using NLTK. Please help.

Comment: Are they all in that format? Because then I'd just look between the colon and the first comma?

Comment: Yes buddy I tried to code it as well.

Comment: Name=re.compile(r'[A-Z]. +[A-Z]. +[A-Za-z]\.')
matches=address.finditer(my_text)

for x in matches:
    print(x)

Comment: sentence.split(':')[1].split(',')[0][1:]

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

rc = re.compile(r":([a-zA-Z\.\s]*)")

Value = "Name of the informant : N. K. Sangle, PC B.No. 1775 Traffic Control Branch, Ahmednagar"

print (rc.search(Value)[1])
```

out Put : N. K. Sangle

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to import a library like regex then you can use built-in string methods:

```
>>> sentence = "Name of the informant : N. K. Sangle, PC B.No. 1775 Traffic Control Branch, Ahmednagar"
>>> name = sentence.split(':')[1].split(',')[0][1:]
>>> print(name)
'N. K. Sangle'
```

This uses [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) which takes a string and splits it into a list. It's then using list indexing (with `[]` to extract the relevant item in the list.

Here's how I built it up.

```
>>> sentence = "Name of the informant : N. K. Sangle, PC B.No. 1775 Traffic Control Branch, Ahmednagar"
'Name of the informant : N. K. Sangle, PC B.No. 1775 Traffic Control Branch, Ahmednagar'

>>> sentence.split(':')
['Name of the informant ',' N. K. Sangle, PC B.No. 1775 Traffic Control Brance, Ahmednagar']

>>> sentence.split(':')[1]
' N. K. Sangle, PC B.No. 1775 Traffic Control Brance, Ahmednagar'

>>> sentence.split(':')[1].split(',')
[' N. K. Sangle', ' PC B.No. 1775 Traffic Control Branch', ' Ahmednagar']

>>> sentence.split(':').split(',')[0]
' N. K. Sangle'

>>> sentence.split(':').split(',')[0][1:]
'N. K. Sangle'
```